# mod_rewrite not working with alphanumeric values

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to do a simple url rewrite using htaccess to convert:

```
example.com/test/?product_name=name-of product
```

to

```
example.com/test/name-of-product
```

To do that, I am using:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule    ^test/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$    test/?product_name=$1   [NC,L]
```

This works fine when the product_name is a number (example.com/test/200/) but does not work when the product_name is alpha or alphanumeric (example.com/test/abc/)

I get Page Not Found when using alpha or alphanumeric value

Everything I have read online seems to tells me that this should work, but I am missing something.  Any ideas why that’s not working?  Or perhaps the best way to accomplish this (make a pretty url)?

> Additional Information.  I did a bit more research, and since this is a WordPress site, /test/ actually is a variable as well, so the site url is

example.com/?page_id=611

and I think I am appending that with the product_name=name-of product, so the url may look like (I think) as

example.com/?page_id=611&product_name=name-of product

but the page_id will always be the same (611).  If what I am thinking is correct, what does the rewite in htaccess looks like?

Thank you for your help

Ray

Comment: `name-of product` is not completely alphanumeric. Forgot to list an actual example? Dir structure? RewriteLog?

Comment: This is a wordpress site, and I have created a page (in wordpress) called test.  So would the dir structure be root/test?  Or is that where the issue is?  example is example.com/test/?product_name=product-name to example.com/test/product_name/.   I will try and get the log

Comment: it  really seems to work. Put at begging of the test.php `echo $_GET['product_name']` to test if this error of htaccess or of php side

Comment: Yes, I have $_GET['product_name'] and I echo that to test the output, when I go to test/?product_name=abc (or 123), I get the right output.  When I do test/123, it echos 123, but test/abc takes me to Page Not Found

Comment: Thanks mario and splash58, your questions got me thinking if this is a mod_rewrite issue or wordpress issue.  I started looking into that and turns out it is a wordpress issue and a solution is at https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule, which works exactly the way I need it to work.  Thanks for the questions to get me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I did more research based on questions by mario and splash58 and turns out that this is a wordpress issue, not mod_rewrite.  This can be resolved using wordpress rewrite API.  Details and examples are on the wordpress website at:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule